# Webexception:remote server returned an error (401)unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net

Giving Exception on

```
HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
```

this line.And Error message is

> remote server returned an error 401 unauthorized

It occures only when am calling web service from other project solution...
This exception is not occuring when calling service from same project solution.

what should I do to remove this exception and get Response from Remote server??
Plz help me.

Comment: Other project might be secured with some username or password.

Comment: You might need to send NetworkCredentials

Comment: Actually there is same file in both projects.Am not aware about location of username and password OR Network credentials is provided in other project. Where should i find it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions can be:

1) add `<identity impersonate="true"></identity>` in web.config

2) If you have credentials

```
using (client = new MyWebService())
{
    var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSUserName"]
    var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WSPassword"]
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    // .. and the call here ..
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't fix your problem.